# In layman's terms, unravel Leo Getz's money laundering scheme in Lethal Weapon 2 (1989)?

Tags: lethal-weapon-2

I fathom everything up to, **but I can't grok anything under**, the horizontal line beneath. I am a visual learner — please explain in simple English with diagrams and pictures!

> *Lethal Weapon II* (Warner Bros) 1989, starring Mel Gibson
> (screenplay by Jeffrey Boam; story by Shane Black and Warren Murphy)
>
> LEO: I also launder money.
>
> RIGGS: How’d you do it?
>
> LEO: Okay. They bring the cash into the bank and deposit it into the account
> of a dummy Finance Company licensed out of the Bahamas. Sometimes
> this takes all day, because we can’t do it all in one deposit.
>
> MURTAUGH: Why not?
>
> LEO: The Bank Secrecy Act. All cash deposits or withdrawals of ten thousand
> dollars or more will generate a CTR . . . ‘Currency Transaction Record’ . . .
> which goes to the IRS.
>
> MURTAUGH: That’s good.
>
> LEO: No, that’s bad. Made my job a lot harder.
>
> RIGGS: That’s what’s good about it, Leo.

---

##### [I got discombobulated starting here.]

> LEO: Anyway . . . after all the deposits have been made, I turn around and issue
> them a cashier’s cheque for the amount of the total deposits minus a
> commission. Cashiers’ cheques are wonderful instruments. As good as
> cash, but they don’t generate a report to the IRS.
>
> MURTAUGH: So now the money is washed, right?
>
> LEO: Yeah. But there’s more . . . The cashier’s cheque is treated as a *loan*. The
> ‘lender’ is the dummy Finance Company. There’s loan documents to support
> it. They can even take a tax deduction on the interest payments
> they’re not making.
>
> MURTAUGH: Leo . . . you’re a crook.

I extracted from [this script](https://archive.org/stream/TheNiceGuys/Lethal%20Weapon_2_djvu.txt).

Comment: You should note that the first part is nowadays **completely fictional**: "All cash deposits or withdrawals of ten thousand dollars or more will generate a CTR"  Anything that *adds up to more than* 10,000 is reported.  Newsflash, the government thought about the idea of "doing two deposits of 9000 !!"  Regarding the second part, it's much much harder to do that in real life, you can't really just sort of use "the same person / bank". Finally in the last say 10 yrs it's become much, much harder to set up overseas bank accounts, as a rule.

Comment: It isn't making sense to you because it doesn't work, or at least is not complete.  The purpose of money laundering is not to avoid paying taxes on dirty money.  It is to pay taxes on dirty money, whilst making it look like it came from a legitimate source.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The money laundering process explained by the [UN](https://syntheticdrugs.unodc.org/syntheticdrugs/en/cybercrime/launderingproceeds/index.html). Picture is from them. As you ask for a very simple diagram with less words, here it is. It's what Leo does in the movie. Your question starts at point #3 (out of 4), where the company pays a fake invoice or takes a fake loan.

In such a system, there are off-shore companies and banks that are just an empty shell.   Dirty money is put in an account, this account issues an invoice or loan to a real company owns by the mob. The money goes legally to this company through the loan (that will never be paid back). Money is now official (being washed/laundered).

In case some g-men (like IRS) want to check the company's Books/records, they find nothing. It's even more opaque because they create companies that hold shares of companies that hold shares of other companies... and so on... It's a spider web.

If you need clarification, please comment.

[image: money laundering diagram]

Comment: I'm not too happy about all the moralistic language here!  Everything mentioned is completely, totally normal and legal and sweet.  Certainly, governments don't *like this happening*, so they apply terms like "dirty" and "laundering".  Governments need every penny they can get to feed the endless-war machine, so they're down on this sort of stuff.

Comment: "*moralistic*"? "*Legal and sweet*"?! We're talking about drug money here.

Comment: @Fattie Those are the widely accepted terms. The question is about money laundering after all. Debates on whether money laundering should be called money laundering are pretty off-topic.

Comment: @Fattie Not too happy about the moralistic language?  Characterizing the government as running an endless-war machine seems a bit moralistic to me.  Not that you're wrong about governments running too many wars...

Answer (score 11):

This answer does not have diagrams and pictures, but is intended to explain in simple terms.

1. Someone sends money to a black box;
2. Someone takes a loan from the black box;
3. The loan **is never paid,** so someone ends up with the money and loan papers to justify the money.

The job of money laundering's crooks is to operate the black box and provide the loan papers.

Comment: Presumably the payment is structured as a loan so no tax is paid on it?